# Neo4j Browser Connection

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, graph, neo4j, cloud

From neo4j browser, when I connect to the database I get the below error. This is purely a cloud based instance.

```
ServiceUnavailable: Could not perform discovery. No routing servers available. Known routing table: RoutingTable[database=default database, expirationTime=0, currentTime=1647599340226, routers=[], readers=[], writers=[]]
```

Can someone help here please?

Thanks
Narayana

Comment: We need more information, this just means server is unreachable

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused mostly by the internet browser as it might block one or more components required for the connection's smooth operation.
The browser's console logs would usually highlight any such resource being blocked.
Disable pop-up/ad blockers for the below URLs and try again:

- https://browser.neo4j.io/
- https://browser.graphapp.io/
- https://bloom.neo4j.io/

Or use try from a different browser.
Reference: ['Could not perform discovery. No routing servers available' while connecting to an Aura DB instance from Neo4j browser](https://aura.support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us/articles/5290730835859--Could-not-perform-discovery-No-routing-servers-available-while-connecting-to-an-Aura-DB-instance-from-Neo4j-browser)